# Can not receive ios notification

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

I want to send ios notification using APNS , but I have noticed that ony access token created by my mobile can recevice notification , while another token created by another devices cannot recieve notification .

For example I have install application in my development iphone and I can receive notifications , but in my another iphone ( Not for development ) I cannot receive any notification .

When Im trying to send notifications to both devices at same time ( in parallel ), I cannot receive any notification in both devices .

But if send independent  notification , only development device can receive.

Comment: Have you checked environment of your app and APNS ?

Comment: Can u tell me how I can check that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phones themselves do not have a push "environment".

An app is either built enabled to operate with the development  push environment or the production push environment (as a *simplified* summary - by default, an app built/installed via Xcode will be enabled for development pushes, while an app built and distributed as an .ipa outside of Xcode will be enabled for production pushes).

If the version of the app installed on the phone is built for the dev environment then pushes must be sent over the push environment and vice versa for production.
The Apple development environment gateway (also know as the sandbox gateway) which your server connects to will be for development:

> ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195

While the production gateway is:

> ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195

Thats some basics, as to your actual problem, you would need to: show your server code that is sending the pushes in parallel; and indicate how you are installing the app on the phone which is not receiving pushes; and indicate how your server is getting the push tokens from the devices in order to diagnose your issue.